# Error creating bean in JUnit test in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, dependency-injection

I am creating application in Spring Boot. I created service that looks that way:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${myprops.hostname}")
    private String host;

    public void callEndpoint() {
        String endpointUrl = this.host + "/endpoint";
        System.out.println(endpointUrl);
    }
}
```

This service will connect to REST endpoint to other application (developed also by me) that will be deployed along. That is why I want to customize hostname in application.properties file (-default, -qa, -dev).

My application builds and works just fine. I tested it by creating controller that calls this service, and it populates `host` field with correct property  from application.properties.

The problem occurs when I try to write test for this class.
When I try this approach:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void callEndpoint() {
        myService.callEndpoint();
    }
}
```

i receive exception:

`org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.ge.bm.wip.comp.processor.service.MyServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'myService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.ge.bm.wip.comp.processor.service.MyService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.`

And some more nested exception. I can post them if it will help.
I suppose that for some reason SpringRunner does not launch this test in Spring context and therefore cannot see bean MyService.

Does anyone know how it can be fixed? I tried normal initialization:

```
private MyService myService = new myService();
```

but then `host` field is `null`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have to annotate your test with `@SpringBootTest` as well.

Try:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @Test
    public void callEndpoint() {
        myService.callEndpoint();
    }
}
```